# AppEngine application NOT responding even though well within quota limits with credit balance

Tags: google-app-engine, odk

If I have a credit balance in my Google AppEngine dashboard for a particular Open Data Kit Aggregate instance which is well within its quota limits, why am I getting this message??

> "AppEngine Application Problem. A problem has occurred that prevents
>   your AppEngine application from responding. Your application may have
>   exceeded its per-minute or daily usage quotas.  Please visit your
>   application dashboard at Google AppEngine. The Billing Status section
>   will indicate what daily or per-minute usage limits your application
>   has exceeded...If neither of those indicate any problems, then your application's Logs may; these are reachable from the dashboard via the Logs link on the left sidebar under the Main heading."

I have search the dashboard far and wide and don't see ANY red flags whatsoever relating to logs, or exceeding any quota limits. I added a new credit card and paid a $3 outstanding bill by making a payment for $20. Hence a $17 credit balance. About to give up.

Comment: Did you look at what the message tells you to look at? It would definitely be helpful. Also, what is your daily budget? that might be blocking you here..

Answer (score 1):

One thing you should definitely do is go to SITE ADMIN -> PREFERENCES and tick "Disable faster background actions"
That is the only reason your quota should be finishing so fast.

Can you give us a screenshot of your logs, particularly datastore read operations, that is usually what spikes over the quota.

If you don't find any issues on your own, post a query on https://groups.google.com/d/forum/opendatakit. They are quite responsive, especially Mitch.